# Start Fragment from Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I'm able to start a Fragment from an Activity.
However Im worried about potential problems with my implementation.

I have two fragments, `FragmentA` and `FragmentB`
And I have 3 activity classes, `Activity1`, `Activity2`, `ResultActivity`

```
public class NavigationTabs extends FragmentActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_tabs_2);

    FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter = new MyTabs(getSupportFragmentManager());
    ....
    ....
 }

 static class MyTabs extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public MyTabs(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position)
        {
                case 0:

                     FragmentA FragA = new FragmentA();  
                     return FragA;

                 case 1:

                     FragmentB FragB = new FragmentB();  
                     return FragB;
      ......
      ......
      }
  }
```

^How I call `FragmentA` and `FragmentB`

`FragmentA` starts `Activity1` via an intent.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

`Activity1` then passes the results of a counter to `ResultActivity`

`ResultActivity` starts(or returns to) `FragmentA` and sets SharedPreferences via onClick like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   if(v.getId()== R.id.button_1){
      SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      Editor edit = sp.edit();
      edit.putInt(passedSavePref, counter);
      edit.commit();

      finish();
}
}
```

`FragmentB` starts `Activity2` via an intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

`Activity2` then passes the results of a counter to `ResultActivity`

`ResultActivity` starts(returns to) `FragmentB` and sets SharedPreferences via onClick like this

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
   if(v.getId()== R.id.button_1){
      SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      Editor edit = sp.edit();
      edit.putInt(passedSavePref, counter);
      edit.commit();

      finish();
}
}
```

This all works for my needs. GC seems fine, its freeing and allocating memory.

`ResultActivty` returns to the correct Fragment, and it sets the SavedPreferences correctly.

Yet it seems very bad implementation. 
For starters, while searching through other questions I've read, "Don't start an Activity directly from a Fragment" the poster also linked to the proper implementation here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks

I've tried calling `Activity1` from `FragmentA` like this, but I don't really see a difference in behavior or performance

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity1.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

So my question is, do I need to finish/remove `FragmentA` when I start `Activity1`, then start `FragmentA` again  from `ResultActivity`using something like

```
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** So what I was trying to was to either kill/finish/pop `FragmentA` so that I could re-start it from `ResultActivity`.
The reason I was tying to do that was because my savedPreferences were not loading when I was going back to `FragmentA` from `ResultActivity`.(well they were saving and loading correctly, but I couldn't see them)

As I understand it from the docs,Fragments go on pause. So calling my loadPreferences method onResume(); loaded my SavedPreferences.

Not marking this as an answer, because I did not implement any of the standard/proper practices of dealing with Fragments `popBackStack();` `FragmentTransactions` etc

Comment: This seems way too complicated. You might get null pointer exception when you try to return to a fragment that's already been detached or removed...

Comment: Yeah you are right. The unnecessary complexity of my approach is mainly due to not knowing/understanding well the lifecycle of fragments and the tools used to manage it. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: What you could do is using the callback pattern you mentioned, where you let the host activity handle all the actions, either launching new activities or fragments. Then your fragment is just a container of a particular view. Using callback pattern is prefered because the activity has all the `Context` stuff.

Comment: Or under your current implementation, make sure to check `null` when returning to fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Quote: "Don't start an Activity directly from a Fragment"

I read the poster who wrote this, and I strongly disagree.  His rationale is that it reduces the modularity of the fragment, and he believes you should impelment an interface to call back to the activity.

I disagree.  It doesn't reduce modularity, in fact it increases it. Why implement a layer of abstraction to do something the fragment is intended to do in every implementation?  Why re-write the same code in every activity, when it can be modularized in the fragment?   In fact fragments wouldn't have their own specialized functions for starting activities if this was against design principles.

For instance, if you start an activity using fragment.startAcitivtyForResult(), the fragment is put directly as the onActivityResult receiver.  Not so if you use your activity instance to directly start the new activity.

2. You do not need to remove framgents before starting a new Activity

Android will pause/stop your fragments, and potentially destroy them and the underlying activity as well if need be.   Android is constantly destroying and recreating activities and fragments, like every time you change the orientation on your screen - the default settings has your activity and fragments commit mass suicide.

This is why functions like OnSaveInstanceState() are so important, because they let your activities and fragments return to a saved state. The general rule of android programming is your activity / fragments should be able to respond to spontaneous death gracefully.

Comment: This is true. However even if you don't remove fragments, there is a chance that you will get null pointer exception due to system routines on the activity, when your activity will return to the previous fragment. So it renders the app potentially unstable.

Comment: 1-From my limited understanding on modularity, and layer of abstraction, as it relates to my implementation, I agree with you.
Thanks for the explanation. 

2-"You do not need to remove framgents before starting a new Activity"
Yeah, I didn't know that. Testing and logging let me see which functions were being called when.

I have no formal training.I learn by tutorials, trial and error, process of elimination, so posts like yours are very helpful.
Thanks for taking the time to explain and shed light on this topic.

Comment: the super.onCreate(bundle) is capable of recreating / reattaching fragments/views that were saved to the bundle, and super.onSaveInstanceState() puts them there.  They write all sorts of data like text in textView, cursor position, scroll states, etc.  Fields that you create in your fragment are in jeopardy of being lost every time the framgent is destroyed, unless you put that data in the bundle yoruself, or move the reference to something that isn't expected to die.